# search by the content and output the folder name in unix

Tags: unix

I am very new to the shell script world. I have done some research but was not able to display the folder.

what I am doing is, to search for a `'string'` in all files, and to display the directory name recursively where is the file containing that string.

for example. if the string appears in `text.txt` which is  `./some/more/final/text.txt`

the output is:

```
 somemorefinal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -rl string . | sed 's#/[^/]*$##'
```

or

```
find ./ -type f | xargs grep string | awk -F/ '$1 = OFS = "";NF--'
```

Comment: my shell does not recognize the -r flag of grep?

Comment: find ./ -type f | xargs grep string |  sed 's#/[^/]*$##'

Comment: find ./ -type f | xargs grep the | awk -F/ '{$1 = "";OFS = "";NF --;print}'

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "my_sought_string_here" `find .`
```

(note: the second set of quotes are back quotes)